# What's wrong with this Ant path?

Tags: java, gwt, ant, classnotfoundexception, gwt-compiler

**Note:** even though this question *involves* GWT, it's really an *Ant* question. All I'm asking is: *is the Ant PATH that I have below a "legal" path?*

I am getting `ClassNotFoundExceptions` on a type (`com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler`) that is packaged inside `gwt-dev.jar` (which as you can see is configured to be on the path below). Does the `gwt.path` look wrong to anyone:

```
<path id="gwt.path">
    <pathelement location="${gen.bin.main.dir}"/>
    <fileset dir="${gen.lib.main.dir}">
        <filename name="gin-2.1.2.jar"/>
        <filename name="guice-3.0.0.jar"/>
        <filename name="guice-assistedinject-3.0.0.jar"/>
        <filename name="gwt-bootstrap-2.2.2.jar"/>
        <filename name="gwt-bootstrap-sources-2.2.2.jar"/>
        <filename name="gwt-dev.jar"/>
        <filename name="gwt-user.jar"/>
        <filename name="javax-inject-1.0.0.jar"/>
        <filename name="requestfactory-apt.jar"/>
        <filename name="requestfactory-client+src.jar"/>
        <filename name="validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar"/>
        <filename name="validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

If now then I will explore other avenues.

Comment: What does `<echo message="${toString:gwt.path}" />` output?

Answer (score 1):

To see if an ant path is correct use the ant [touch](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/touch.html) command:

```
<touch file="myfile"/>
```

This is similar to the unix touch command and should create an empty file named myfile in that path, if the path is correct.

In this case, are you trying to add some jars to the classpath? In that case you should use the classpath element and not path.

Comment: Thanks @jhadesdev (+1) - but when I change the outer `<path>` to `<classpath>` (and same for its closing tag) I get a new error: `BUILD FAILED
/home/myUser/MyProj/build.xml:81: Problem: failed to create task or type classpath
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.` Thoughts?

Comment: @TicketMonster What's your version of Ant?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was bad Ant. All the `<fileset>` elements need to be `<pathelement location="the-jar"/>` instead.